# Definition of a function with a list in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I want to write a function that will take any list and give me back that "sum" answer. Now I'm doing it for "recherche" but the point is to do it for any type in the list. That's what my code look like.

```
TYPE_RECHERCHE = "recherche"

une_formation = [
    [ TYPE_DIRIGEE, 7.50 ],
    [ TYPE_PRESENTATION, 4.5 ],
    [ TYPE_DIRIGEE, 2.00 ],
    [ TYPE_CONFERENCE, 7.0 ],
    [ TYPE_ATELIER, 2.25 ],
    [ TYPE_GROUPE_DISCUSSION, 3.00 ],
    [ TYPE_RECHERCHE, 1 ],
    [ TYPE_LECTURE, 4.0 ],
    [ TYPE_RECHERCHE, 4 ],
    [ TYPE_RECHERCHE, 2.5 ],
    [ TYPE_PRESENTATION, 3.5 ],
    [ TYPE_REDACTION, 5.5 ],
    [ TYPE_LECTURE, 10.0 ]
]


temps_formation_recherche = []
a = -1 
while a < 12:
    a = a + 1
    if une_formation[a][0] == "recherche":
        temps_formation_recherche.append(une_formation[a][1])

sum(temps_formation_recherche) # this will return 7.5
```

Comment: What is the question? What is your end goal?

Comment: u see, after the code part a = -1.......

Comment: What is it doing wrong?

Comment: im trying to put that into a function. that will take the list "une_formation" or any other list that look like that one. and return me all value associate with "type_recherche" or "type_dirigee" ......

Comment: `def` is nowhere in your code.  If you are _trying to def a function_, you're not trying very hard.

Comment: im trying but i didn't write it here to not mix you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little difficult to understand exactly what you're after, but try this:

```
def mon_fonction(une_formation, TYPE_RECHERCHE):
    tot = 0
    liste = []
    for quel, val in une_formation:
        if quel == TYPE_RECHERCHE:
            tot += val
            liste.append(val)
    print "Les vals sont:", liste
    print "en tout:", tot
    return tot
```

Comment: i will try with this thank you

Comment: this one work perfectly thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Or to use `groupby` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import groupby

def sum_by_type(une_formation, TYPE_String):
    return [sum(i[1] for i in group) for key, group in groupby(sorted(une_formation, key = lambda i: i[0]), lambda i: i[0]) if key == TYPE_String ][0]
```

Comment: thank you for the info, im learning the basic of python, i think this is too advance for me right now, but thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can define your function so that it takes the thing you are trying to find as a parameter. Then you can add the value of each found item to a temporary variable - it seems like you were almost there with your temporary list.
Such as:

```
def find_total(toFind):
    temps_formation_recherche = 0
    a = -1
    while a < 12:
        a += 1
        if une_formation[a][0] == toFind:
            temps_formation_recherche += une_formation[a][1]

    return temps_formation_recherche
```

Which in the case of `TYPE_RECHERCHE` will return `7.5`. In the case of `TYPE_DIRIGEE`, returns `9.5`.

---

You can further optimise your code by using list comprehension:

```
def find_total(toFind):
    return sum([x[1] for x in une_formation if x[0] == toFind])

print(find_total(TYPE_RECHERCHE))  # prints 7.5
print(find_total(TYPE_DIRIGEE))    # prints 9.5
```

This will take the original list, create a list containing only the number part of each element which matches, then uses the `sum` function to add them all up.

Comment: thank you very much for the help, i  appreciate that.

Comment: i try this one and it dosent work